# How to Query for Record Id using BreezeJS

Tags: breeze

I created a new entry with breeze, on submit i want to immediately get the id of the record using the basic fields that i used to create the record like using email, please how do i get the Id of the new record using breeze.

this is what i have done

```
bind gotoStep2() with the save button which pass in the value of the textbox to use as predicate, 
// the save() method successfully create the record to the database, 

function gotoStep2(firstName, lastName, email) {
        save();
        console.log('Save log')
        // Get the ProfileID
        return datacontext.profile.getProfileId(firstName, lastName, email)
            .then(function (data) {
                console.log('Id retrived is: ' + data.Id); // check the value returned
                vm.profile = data; 
                //$location.path('/step-two/' + data.Id);
                // Todo: pass the value to the next route
            }, function (error) {
                logError('Unable to get speaker');
            });
    }


function getProfileId(firstName, lastName, email) {
        var self = this;
        var predicate = Predicate.create('firstName', '==', firstName)
                        .and('lastName', '==', lastName)
                        .and('email', '==', email);
        var profiles = [];

        return EntityQuery.from('Profiles')
            .select('id')
            .where(predicate)
            .toType(entityName)
            .using(self.manager).execute()
            .then(querySucceeded, self._queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            profiles = data.results;
            self.log('Retrieved [Profile by email] from remote data source', profiles.length, true);
            return profiles;
        }
    }
```

from the above query dont always get any return value

Thanks

Comment: I need a sample query on how to get record id by querying with predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand your question, but it sounds like you want to get the id of a newly saved record immediately after the save. If so then the answer below applies.

When the save promise resolves it returns both the list of saved entities as well as a *keyMappings* array for any entities whose ids changed as a result of the save. i.e. a mapping from temporary to real ids. i.e. (Documented here: http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_saveChanges)

```
myEntityManager.saveChanges().then(function (saveResult) {
  // entities is an array of entities that were just saved.
  var entitites = saveResult.entities;
  var keyMappings = saveResult.keyMappings;
  keyMappings.forEach(function(km) {
    var tempId = km.tempValue;
    var newId = km.realValue;
  });
});
```

On the other hand if you have an entity and you just want its 'key' you can use the *EntityAspect.getKey* method. (see http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityAspect.html#method_getKey)

```
// assume order is an order entity attached to an EntityManager.
var entityKey = order.entityAspect.getKey();
```